# How do I reserve screen space for my VB application

Tags: vb.net, screen, sidebar, dock

Hi I know this may seem like a simple question, but I have been searching the internet for weeks and can't seem to find a straight answer.

Basically I am trying to make my own sidebar that will always be on the side of my screen. Similar to how the Maxthon browser sidebar works. I want ALL other programs including the windows desktop to be pushed to the side of my app. I basically want my form to function like the windows taskbar.

Any ideas on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want the taskbar inside your form?

Comment: The Windows taskbar is an example of an AppBar.  You will need to use pinvoke to do this.  You would need to look at the SHAppBarMessage pinvoke function.  [Here is an article in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6741/AppBar-using-C) which should give you some ideas on how to accomplish your goal.